# UIScrollView and presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I add UITableViewController in UIScrollView. When I call

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Email"];
    [picker setMessageBody:currentcelltext isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

MFMailComposeViewController is coming in UIScrollView. So, I can't press cancel and send button.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you set MessageUI.framework in your xcode project..
After you have to set delegate in .h file..

than , 
you have to create one more method..

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have fixed the issues.
This answer is for those who might come to this post with the expectation of answer.

To fix this you have to use delegation pattern. I assume all the pages in your scrollview are viewcontroller instances and scrollview is subview to viewcontroller.

This answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/626946/451867 can help you to implement delegate pattern in your project,

You can read developer docs for more info - [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)